# ASP.NET MVC 3 application on LB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, load-balancing

We have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application deployed in production with 3 servers on an LB. The application accessed via SSL and is working in each of these servers separately. When it is on the domain with LB the same Urls goes on infinite loop.  Any thoughts, Thanks in advance

-George

Comment: You should try give some more details.. what is the HTTP Error? do you have log files? I assume you are running IIS, which version? What is your load balancer? anyways sounds like a Server / Load Balancing Issue and you may get more help on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Yes it is on IIS 7.5, not sure about the type of load balancer, I may get more detail later today,